# Native packed JavaFX app not working on windows

Tags: windows, javafx, javafx-8

When creating a native JavaFX by using the gradle plugin (http://goo.gl/yiO0XK) everything works great on MacOS. On Windows I will get an EXE file. When starting the file there is a message that the MSCVP100.dll is missing. I installed the .Net 4 Runtime and the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistribution Package (see this link http://goo.gl/NOMxYo). 
If I start the exe now I will get two error dialogs:

> Configuration file is not found!
>   C:\Users\Hendrik\Desktop\app\package.cfg

and

> Failed to find main application jar! 
>   Failed to parse package configuration file

I think the second one depends on the first one. Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working now :)

This was just my fault and my lack of knowledge of windows...
When building a native bundle on windows you will get a folder with the exe, an icon file and 2 folder (app, runtime). You can't just copy the exe. To run the app you need all the content. So you need to copy / move the complete folder and not only the exe.